# Unable to install Blackberry Apps via BlackBerry Desktop Software

Tags: blackberry

I want to installed an developed apps into blackberry 8520 v5.0 but it prompt me error `No additional apps can be found ...`. I not sure what is the problem? Device or .alx file problem? I am developing using SDK 7.0.0 but i had installed SDK 5.0. Although I changed to 5.0 also cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please change on .alx file at following.

```
<fileset Java="1.49" _blackberryVersion="[5.0.0)">
<directory >
5.0.0
</directory>
<files >
```